# Press JButton to draw a ball, the ball is not visible

Tags: java

So, I want to draw a ball whenever the user presses JButton. My problem is that the ball is not visible after I call revalidate() and repaint(). Am I forgetting something?
Here is my code, I have another class for the queue and stack that's why I extended Queueue. My buttons are visible and I know they work when I press them, it's jst that the ball doesn't show up on the screen. Earlier I tried to have my void paintComponent in my ActionListener but it would not work. I then wanted to just call the method but because of the Graphics g parameter it would not work as well. So I saw similar issue where someone suggested to use boolean

```
public class Main extends Queueue {

static boolean clicked = false;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if(clicked) {
        
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(60, 60, 15, 15);
        
    
    }

    }

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Queueue qq = new Queueue();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Queue");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Stack");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("Ball");
    f.setSize(700, 500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    p.setBackground(Color.RED);
    p.add(b1);
    p.add(b2);
    p.add(b3);
    f.add(p);
    f.setVisible(true);
    
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            qq.Q();
            
        }
        
    });
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            qq.S();
            
        }
        
    });

 b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            clicked = true;
            f.revalidate();
            f.repaint();
        
            
        }
        
    });
```

Comment: You're defining `paintComponent` on a class that you don't even instantiate. To be used to paint a component, `paintcComponent` must be defined on a graphical component that is added to your frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some syntax errors which I corrected. I also trimmed it down to more clearly demonstrate the procedure.  Here is a working version that just paints the ball.

```
public class Main extends JPanel {
    
    static boolean clicked = false;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Main m = new Main();
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Ball");
        f.setSize(700, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        f.add(m);
        m.add(b3);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                clicked = true;
                f.repaint();
                
            }
        });
        
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (clicked) {
            
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(60, 60, 15, 15);
            
        }
    }
}
```

- Your class should extend `JPanel`
- Add it to the `JFrame`.
- Add the `JButton` to `Main` instance
- and in `paintComponent` call `super.paintComponent(g)` first.

Check out [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more information on how to paint.

In response to your comments, the following should work.  The main issue is that you need to have the paintComponent inside a `JPanel`, not as a method in `Queueue`.

```
public class Main extends Queueue {
    
    static boolean clicked = false;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Main m = new Main();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (clicked) {
                
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillOval(60, 60, 15, 15);
                
            }
        }
        };
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Ball");
        f.setSize(700, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        f.add(panel);
        panel.add(b3);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                clicked = true;
                f.repaint();
                
            }
        });
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I have another class that I need in this one. That is why I could not extend JPanel, cuz I already extended another class. Is there some way to fix it?

Comment: Did Queueue extend JPanel?

Comment: No, Queueue does not extend any other class. I have the queueue class only to create stack and queue in it.

Comment: I edited my answer.  Check out the new code at the end.  You will need to add the other buttons yourself.

Comment: I have another question, I hope you can answear. So now my JPanel does not have background, so what I did was adding backgroud to my Jframe instead and it works just fine, but my question is, why did the backgrond dissapeared? p.setBackground(Color.RED); is not working but when I change it to f.setBackground(Color.RED); it works just fine. I usually set the background on JPanel and not JFrame

Comment: It works for me.  Did you put `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first statement in `paintComponent()`?